# Grouping SQL results from a Union (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, group-by, union

I use duplicate query with `group by` and `union` to get my result but the result don't show like I want.

The query:

```
select  
    league , 
    count(*) as total_1   
from 
    Games  
where
    score_away is not null 
    and score_home is not null   
group by 
    League

union 

select 
    league , 
    count(*) as total_2    
from 
    Games  
where
    score_away is null 
    and score_home is null   
group by 
    League
```

**Games Table**

```
 leugue      gameID     score_home     score_away
-------------------------------------------------
       1        10           2               0
       1        11           1               1
       1        12           NUll            NULL
       2        13           2               0
       1        14           NUll            NULL
       1        15           1               1
       2        16           2               2
       2        17           2               4
```

Current results:

```
    League     total1
------------------------
        1        3
        1        2  
        2        3
```

Expected results:

```
    League     total1    total2
-------------------------------
        1        3        2
        2        3        0
```

Comment: use a join instead of a union. Note, league 2 should have NULL for one of the totals in you expected results

Comment: It'll be easier if you can show us the table structure. (Refer [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need all results (without removing duplicates) you might want to use UNION ALL instead of UNION. In that case the results will become:

```
   League     total1
------------------------
        1        20
        2        10
        1        40
        2        10
```

However, to get the desired result, you may want to try:

```
SELECT
    league = COALESCE(Totals1.league, Totals2.league),
    total_1 = COALESCE(Totals1.total_1, 0),
    total_2 = COALESCE(Totals2.total_2, 0)
FROM
    (SELECT league, COUNT(*) as total_1
     FROM Games
     WHERE score_away is not null and score_home is not null
     GROUP BY league) as Totals1
    FULL JOIN
    (SELECT league, COUNT(*) as total_2
     FROM Games
     WHERE score_away is null and score_home is null
     GROUP BY league) as Totals2
    ON Totals1.league = Totals2.league;
```

Edit: Just made a fix on the totals in the result to return 0 instead of NULL.

Edit 2:
Based on your requested extension in your comments, I modified my query to include percentage calculations as follows:

```
SELECT
    league = COALESCE(Totals1.league, Totals2.league),
    total_1 = COALESCE(Totals1.total_1, 0),
    total_2 = COALESCE(Totals2.total_2, 0),
    percent_1 = 100 * COALESCE(Totals1.total_1, 0) / (COALESCE(Totals1.total_1, 0) + COALESCE(Totals2.total_2, 0)),
    percent_2 = 100 * COALESCE(Totals2.total_2, 0) / (COALESCE(Totals1.total_1, 0) + COALESCE(Totals2.total_2, 0))
FROM
    (SELECT league, COUNT(*) AS total_1
     FROM Games
     WHERE score_away IS NOT NULL AND score_home IS NOT NULL
     GROUP BY league) AS Totals1
    FULL JOIN
    (SELECT league, COUNT(*) as total_2
     FROM Games
     WHERE score_away IS NULL AND score_home IS NULL
     GROUP BY league) AS Totals2
    ON Totals1.league = Totals2.league
ORDER BY percent_1;
```

To make the percent calculations more readable, you might place the original query as a subquery in a table expression. Like this:

```
SELECT
    league,
    total_1,
    total_2,
    percent_1 = 100 * total_1 / (total_1 + total_2),
    percent_2 = 100 * total_2 / (total_1 + total_2)
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            league = COALESCE(Totals1.league, Totals2.league),
            total_1 = COALESCE(Totals1.total_1, 0),
            total_2 = COALESCE(Totals2.total_2, 0)
        FROM
            (SELECT league, COUNT(*) AS total_1
             FROM Games
             WHERE score_away IS NOT NULL AND score_home IS NOT NULL
             GROUP BY league) AS Totals1
            FULL JOIN
            (SELECT league, COUNT(*) as total_2
             FROM Games
             WHERE score_away IS NULL AND score_home IS NULL
             GROUP BY league) AS Totals2
            ON Totals1.league = Totals2.league
    ) AS Sub
ORDER BY percent_1;
```

I personally dislike complex "anonymous" table expressions in a FROM clause and would convert it to a common table expression, like this:

```
WITH
    Sub AS
    (
        SELECT
            league = COALESCE(Totals1.league, Totals2.league),
            total_1 = COALESCE(Totals1.total_1, 0),
            total_2 = COALESCE(Totals2.total_2, 0)
        FROM
            (SELECT league, COUNT(*) AS total_1
                FROM Games
                WHERE score_away IS NOT NULL AND score_home IS NOT NULL
                GROUP BY league) AS Totals1
            FULL JOIN
            (SELECT league, COUNT(*) as total_2
                FROM Games
                WHERE score_away IS NULL AND score_home IS NULL
                GROUP BY league) AS Totals2
            ON Totals1.league = Totals2.league
    )
SELECT
    league,
    total_1,
    total_2,
    percent_1 = 100 * total_1 / (total_1 + total_2),
    percent_2 = 100 * total_2 / (total_1 + total_2)
FROM Sub
ORDER BY percent_1;
```

And when refactoring the query like that, I would also convert the other two table expressions (the two SELECT subqueries on the Games table) to common table expressions:

```
WITH
    Totals1 AS
    (
        SELECT league, COUNT(*) AS total_1
        FROM Games
        WHERE score_away IS NOT NULL AND score_home IS NOT NULL
        GROUP BY league
    ),
    Totals2 AS
    (
        SELECT league, COUNT(*) as total_2
        FROM Games
        WHERE score_away IS NULL AND score_home IS NULL
        GROUP BY league
    ),
    Sub AS
    (
        SELECT
            league = COALESCE(Totals1.league, Totals2.league),
            total_1 = COALESCE(Totals1.total_1, 0),
            total_2 = COALESCE(Totals2.total_2, 0)
        FROM
            Totals1
            FULL JOIN Totals2 ON Totals1.league = Totals2.league
    )
SELECT
    league,
    total_1,
    total_2,
    percent_1 = 100 * total_1 / (total_1 + total_2),
    percent_2 = 100 * total_2 / (total_1 + total_2)
FROM Sub
ORDER BY percent_1;
```

Of course, the same can be done with the original query from LukStorms by placing it in a common table expression:

```
WITH
    Sub AS
    (
        SELECT
            league,
            total_1 = SUM(CASE WHEN score_away IS NOT NULL AND score_home IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
            total_2 = SUM(CASE WHEN score_away IS NULL AND score_home IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        FROM Games
        GROUP BY league
    )
SELECT
    league,
    total_1,
    total_2,
    percent_1 = 100 * total_1 / (total_1 + total_2),
    percent_2 = 100 * total_2 / (total_1 + total_2)
FROM Sub
ORDER BY percent_1;
```

Again, in this case, as I see it, LukStorms' query is shorter, more elegant and probably faster.

NB 1: The percentages are currently integer numbers. If you want fractional percentages, you may replace 100 with 100.0

NB 2: When using common table expressions (using the WITH clause) in a SQL script or a stored procedure, note that it will be required to delimit the previous query (before the WITH keyword) with a semicolon. Otherwise, SQL Server will complain with an error.

Comment: You're welcome. Perhaps it's not the most elegant solution, but it is the first solution I could come up with.

Comment: I also like LukStorms' answer. It's shorter and probably even faster.

Comment: I can add another Coulmn with precent  total1/total 2 and then show that by big to small (order by new column)?

Comment: @alex1121 Maybe. If so, total2 in the result set may never be zero, since dividing by zero will result in an error. In your case, it would be required that for every league value, there is at least one record in the table where both  score_away and score_home values are NULL... Is that correct?

Comment: @alex1121 I assume that score_away and score_home will be empty for matches that are not yet played. So I assume that total_1 is the number of played games and total_2 is the number of games still to play (for a certain league). Can you confirm or deny this please? This would result in a new understanding and a new perspective on your problem.

Comment: in real case its never be null or 0 so i can dividing ant row

Comment: This is not the query that I need to divide. I have another query that I use the same code but there I need the division column

Comment: On another  query null or zero is not part of value

Comment: I just updated my answer to include percentage calculations. However, I am not sure if the calculations are correct, since I assumed total_1 and total_2 stand for the number of played games and the number of unplayed games respectively. Hope it helps anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do this kind of thing without UNION or JOINS.
Simply use a GROUP BY and SUM the calculated 1 or 0 (via a CASE or IIF).

Then it'll become easier to add additional totals using the same trick.

```
select 
 league, 
 sum(case when score_away is not null and score_home is not null then 1 else 0 end) as total1_has_away_and_home,
 sum(iif(score_away is null and score_home is null, 1, 0)) as total2_no_away_or_home
from Games g
group by league;
```

**Example snippet:**

```
declare @Games table (league int, gameID int, score_home int, score_away int);

insert into @Games (league, gameID, score_home, score_away) values
(1, 10, 2, 0),(1, 11, 1, 1),(1, 12, NULL, NULL),(1, 14, NULL, NULL),(1, 15, 1, 1),
(2, 13, 2, 0),(2, 16, 2, 2),(2, 17, 2, 4);

select 
 league, 
 sum(case when score_away is not null and score_home is not null then 1 else 0 end) as total1_has_away_and_home,
 sum(case when score_away is null and score_home is null then 1 else 0 end) as total2_no_away_or_home
from @Games g
group by league;
```

It is still possible to use a UNION ALL for this.
Just by adding an extra field to the selects used in the union.
Then group that result.

For example:

```
select league, sum(total_1) as total_1, sum(total_2) as total_2 
from 
(
    select league, count(*) as total_1, 0 as total_2
    from Games
    where score_away is not null
      and score_home is not null
    group by league

    union all

    select league, 0, count(*)
    from Games
    where score_away is null
      and score_home is null
    group by league
) q
group by league;
```

But it's a less efficient way to do it.
*(Btw, a `UNION` removes duplicates, but a `UNION ALL` doesn't)*